# “Space and Time Efficient” way of finding all anagram groups

Tags: java, algorithm, hash-map

I have written a program to find all anagram groups in a text file. I used first 26 Prime numbers as a mapper for 26 characters for finding anagram groups (Since character_set of all anagrams of a particular word are same, the products of the anagrams are also same ). After finding product of anagram I put **(product, anagrams)** pair into HashMap for retrieving later. But I think my solution of retrieving anagrams for particular character_set is not efficient although it is working. I need best practice for my case for iterating through HashMap. Here is the code:

```
public class Find_All_Anagrams_In_File {

// First 26 Primes for corresponding Alphabet letters
private static final int[] PRIMES = new int[] { 2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 41, 43, 47, 53, 59, 
                                        61, 67, 71, 73, 79, 83, 89, 97, 101, 103, 107, 109, 113 };

private static long calcProduct(char[] letters) {
    long res = 1L;
    for (char c: letters) {
        if (c < 65) { // ASCII A = 65
            return -1L;
        }
        int index = c - 65;
        res = res * PRIMES[index];
    }
    return res;
}

public static Map<Long, StringBuffer>  findAllAnagrams(String[] file) {

    Map<String, Long> anagrams = new HashMap<String, Long>();
    Map<Long, StringBuffer> result = new HashMap<Long, StringBuffer>();

    for (String word: file) {
        long product = calcProduct( word.toUpperCase().toCharArray() );
        anagrams.put(word, product);
    }

    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();

    for (String word: file) {
        long product = calcProduct( word.toUpperCase().toCharArray() );

        if (result.get(product) == null) 
            result.put(product, sb.append("" + word));
        else 
            result.put(product, sb.append(result.get(product) + "," + word));
        sb = new StringBuffer();
    }
    return result;
}

@SuppressWarnings({"rawtypes" })
public static void main(String[] args) {

    /*
     *  for,fro,rof
     *  tentak,takten
     *  aks,kas
     *  xew,wex,xwe
     *  marza,maraz
     *  nakra,karan
     *  simple,mislep
     *  
     */
    String[] file = {"for", "fro", "aks", "ten", "xew", "kas", 
                     "uvn", "marza", "take", "random", "tentak", "nakra", 
                     "recursion", "basket", "simple", "karan", "rof", "bike", 
                     "wex", "xwe", "takten", "mislep", "maraz", "kasal"};

    Map<Long, StringBuffer> result = findAllAnagrams(file);

    Iterator iter = result.entrySet().iterator();
    while (iter.hasNext()) {
        Map.Entry pair = (Map.Entry) iter.next();
        String[] anagrams = pair.getValue().toString().split(","); 
        if (anagrams.length > 1) {
            for (int i=0;i<anagrams.length; i++) {
                System.out.print(anagrams[i] + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }

    }

  }
}

Result :
> nakra karan 
> tentak takten
> xew wex xwe 
> marza maraz 
> for fro rof 
> aks kas 
> simple mislep
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### `calcProduct`

You don't need the `L` on these lines:

> ```
> long res = 1L;
> return -1L;
> ```

Instead of explaining what 65 is in a comment:

> ```
>     if (c < 65) { // ASCII A = 65
> ```

You can use `'A'` directly. And checking `c < 'A'` is not enough. You should also check `c > 'Z'`.

The method rewritten:

```
private static long calcProduct(char[] letters) {
    long res = 1;
    for (char c : letters) {
        if (c < 'A' || c > 'Z') {
            return -1;
        }
        int index = c - 'A';
        res = res * PRIMES[index];
    }
    return res;
}
```

#### `findAllAnagrams`

Instead of `StringBuffer`, it's recommended to use `StringBuilder`.

Instead of `new HashMap<Long, StringBuffer>()` you can use the diamond operator `<>` to simplify.

The `anagrams` map is written to but never read. You can remove it.

`file` is a poor name for an array of words. (`words` would be better)

The concatenation in `sb.append("" + word)` is pointless, as `sb.append(word)` has the same effect.

In general, instead of concatenation inside `sb.append(...)`, it's recommended to chain `.append(...).append(...)` calls.

Instead of creating a new `StringBuffer` in every iteration of the loop, you could just create when it's actually needed: when putting the first word in the map.

Finally, it's recommended to always use braces on single-statement if-else conditions.

The method rewritten:

```
public static Map<Long, StringBuilder> findAllAnagrams(String[] words) {
    Map<Long, StringBuilder> result = new HashMap<>();

    for (String word : words) {
        long product = calcProduct(word.toUpperCase().toCharArray());

        StringBuilder sb = result.get(product);
        if (sb == null) {
            result.put(product, new StringBuilder(word));
        } else {
            sb.append(",").append(word);
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

But, this is not nearly good enough. It would be better to use a `List<String>` as the values:

```
public static Map<Long, List<String>> findAllAnagrams(String[] words) {
    Map<Long, List<String>> result = new HashMap<>();

    for (String word : words) {
        long product = calcProduct(word.toUpperCase().toCharArray());

        List<String> anagrams = result.get(product);
        if (anagrams == null) {
            anagrams = new ArrayList<>();
            result.put(product, anagrams);
        }
        anagrams.add(word);
    }
    return result;
}
```

#### `main`

You should not suppress the raw types warning but fix it. The loop could have been written like this:

```
for (Map.Entry<Long, StringBuilder> entry : result.entrySet()) {
```

And since you don't need the keys in the loop body, it's better to iterate over the values:

```
    for (List<String> anagrams : findAllAnagrams(file).values()) {
        if (anagrams.size() > 1) {
            for (String word : anagrams) {
                System.out.print(word + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Actually I knew that my code is not neat but could not enhance it, but your comments gave a good understanding of neat coding style